# notifyDataSetChanged() Not working with baseAdapter and custom ListView

Tags: android, listview

I need the ListView shows the data row by row

So, here is sample from the code:

```
public class ClassName extends AppCompatActivity {
  ListView _listView;
  List <Info> myList;
  CustomAdapterClass myAdapted;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myActivity);
        _listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.viewListView);
        myList= new ArrayList<>();

        myAdapted = new CustomAdapterClass();
        _listView.setAdapter(myAdapted);
        CallingSomeMethodToGetData (SomeData myData);

                  DoThisInBackground{ 
                    myList.clear();
                    Info info;
                    int k=0;
                    for (SomeData  object: myData){
                       Log.i("k:", String.valueOf(k));
                       k++;
                        info = new Info();
                        info.addData(object.getdata());
                        myList.add(info)
                        myAdapted.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        SystemClock.sleep(400);
                    }
                }
    }  

 class  CustomAdapterClass extends BaseAdapter{
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return myList.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return myList.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            Log.i("I: ", String.valueOf(i));
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view, null);
            TextView  _textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name_CustomView);

             _textView .setText(mysList.get(i).getMyData());

            return view;
        }
    }

    }
```

The behavior that I'm getting is that the `ListView` is not updated until all data are loaded to `myList`.

In other words, I'm getting `k` printed in log for every `info` and when all data is loaded then `I`  starts to print in the log
I tried to reduce the code as much as possible, so It can be read

Comment: So, where should I call notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: Ok, I just checked it is not the case of background and UI. where I am calling the myAdapted.notifyDataSetChanged() it is actually calling it but it is not working

Comment: where did you add the `new Info()` into the `myList`?

Comment: and you want to add the items to `myList` one by one?

Comment: right after the `info.addData(object.getdata())` I missed it when I modified the code. Still not able to get it row by row in the ListView

Comment: You should use `RecyclerView` for this it is more flexible and can handle dynamic data pretty well

Answer (score 0):

> NotifyDataSetChanged
>   should be called from UI Thread.

Also, you can consider using RecyclerView for better performance. It also exposes the

> public final void notifyItemChanged(int position, @Nullable Object payload)

This way you can update only a particular item as well.

Comment: I'm reading the data from online database. I don't wont the user to wait for all data to be downloaded to see it. I need to view each data once I get

Comment: @SHADOW.NET Check the updated answer. Consider using recycler view as it will solve your use case. Also, notifyDataSetChanged is discouraged when you know which item is updated.

There are even more optimized way as well https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00

Comment: Actually, it is not the case of different threads. I just checked without DoInBackground and it is not working

Comment: @SHADOW.NET you are getting the data and update Info Object info.addData(object.getdata());

But where are you updating the data in the adapter? If you don't update the data notifyDataSetChanged is useless

Comment: it is there right after the `info.addData(object.getdata())` I missed it when I modified the code.

Comment: possible to share the exact code? if you are running it on main thread, it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ..
define adapter constructor ..
below code define into adapter..

```
    private Context context;
    private List<Info>mylist=new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomAdapterClass(Context context, List<Info> mylist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mylist = mylist;
    }
```

after getting data then define adapter and bind into listview

```
    myAdapted = new CustomAdapterClass(this,mList); // if fragement then used getActivity().
    _listView.setAdapter(myAdapted);


                    myAdapted.notifyDataSetChanged();
```